# Node.js gives error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gmail-api

I am new to node.js and I am doing functionality of fetching all email address from Gmail. After getting responses I am sending responses into jade template. After getting single response I am getting en error in terminal:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

My code is as below:

```
module.exports.getmailist =  function(req , res) {

    var google = require('googleapis');
    var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
    var email_list = Array();
    var myObject = Array();
    var accounting = [];
    var messageIds = [];
    var jsonString = false;
    var employees = {};
    var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
    var oauth2Client = new OAuth2("--MY CLIENT ID--","SECRET ID","REDIRECT URL");
    oauth2Client.credentials = { access_token: req.session.access_token};

    var addData = function (req,response) {
        console.log(response);
        res.render('getmailist',{title: 'Product Template', result: response});
    }

    gmail.users.messages.list({ userId: 'me', 'q': "inbox", auth: oauth2Client}, function(err, response) {
        for(var i = 0; i< response.messages.length; i++) {
            //console.log(response.messages[i].id);
            gmail.users.messages.get({ userId: 'me', id:response.messages[i].id , auth: oauth2Client}, function(error , resp) {

            if(resp != "")
            {
                addData(req,resp)
            }
        });
    }

    return true;
    });
};
```

In `console.log(response)`, I get first datavalue of email as obejct and then below error is displayed.

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:690:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/var/www/nodegoogle/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:700:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/var/www/nodegoogle/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:154:12)
at fn (/var/www/nodegoogle/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:934:10)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/var/www/nodegoogle/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:374:12)
at View.render (/var/www/nodegoogle/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:93:8)
at EventEmitter.app.render (/var/www/nodegoogle/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:566:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (/var/www/nodegoogle/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:938:7)
at addData (/var/www/nodegoogle/lib/callbacks/routes.js:63:11)
at /var/www/nodegoogle/lib/callbacks/routes.js:74:13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because the first step of your iteration that reaches `addData(req,resp)` is sending the response. Remember: the `render` method ends the response.

If you want to loop through `response.messages` array and perform an operation for each item before sending the response, you have to make sure to call `addDate(req,res)` only after the end of your loop.

Take a look at [`async.each`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#each) from the [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module. An example from the docs:

```
async.each(openFiles, function( file, callback) {

  // Perform operation on file here. 
  console.log('Processing file ' + file);

  if( file.length > 32 ) {
    console.log('This file name is too long');
    callback('File name too long');
  } else {
    // Do work to process file here 
    console.log('File processed');
    callback();
  }
  }, function(err){
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error 
    if( err ) {
      // One of the iterations produced an error. 
      // All processing will now stop. 
      console.log('A file failed to process');
    } else {
      console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
    }
});
```

So, in your scenario, you just have to do your stuff on each item (calling the local `callback` after each one, of course) and call your `addData(req,resp)` just at the last callback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,                                                                               after applying async.each loop and in async.each loop , i am using  gmail.users.messages.get call. and outside of async.loop , i can not get response , it is undefined . and i don't understand about callback  you  mentioned in last.

Comment: `async.each` receives 3 arguments: first, the array to be traversed, second, a function that'll be called for each item in the array and lastly, a callback that'll be called when all items were processed or an error occured. This is the callback I mentioned, and is where you should call your `addData(req, resp)` method.